# how to get emailid of public profile by using linkein search api...?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

i am creating an application in c#.
I do want to get email id of public profile....
is it possible to get email id through search profile linkedin api or any other alternative.

thanks with regards.
plz do reply.

Comment: No it's not possible. There are plenty of threads asking why, which has not been answered. We can only assume it's a privacy issue.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to get a user's email via the API.